# CSS: limit image width to half page width if it's narrower than the page

Tags: html, css

I have an image floated to the left of some text:

```
<style>
  img {
    float: left;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <img src="anything.jpg">
  <p>Lots of text.
</div>
```

The image could have any dimensions. I would like to do the following using just CSS, across all form factors:

- if the image is at least as wide as the page, display it full width (width: 100%); and
- if the image is narrower than the page, restrict its width to a maximum of half the page width (max-width: 50%).

Is that possible?

**Edit**

Ok, *not possible* is what I feared, but I really hoped I was just missing something.

I can't create CSS rules/media queries dynamically, all the content is static (in fact there's no server).

I'm wondering if there may be a kludge that's Good Enough: adding a class to the images depending on their size (e.g. .img-500 for images with a width 500px to 599px, .img-600 for 600px to 699px....), and using media queries based on those:

```css
@media (min-width: 501px) {
  .img-500 {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Would be interested to hear if anyone has tried that, or knows of a reason that approach is doomed?

Comment: Not without JavaScript

Comment: calculte its width respective to viewport width of winow with jquery and apply the rules.

Comment: _“Is that possible?”_ – no, that is not possible. CSS has no way to “check” the condition “is the image at least as wide as the page.” // I would read the image dimensions server-side, and then create appropriate CSS rules/media queries dynamically.

Comment: Seems restricting an image (no matter what size) based on screen orientation, width and height might work better. Media queries can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, conditionals on width can't be done with CSS only. However you can use two classes one with `width: 50%` and the other `width: 100%` & use JavaScript to switch between them when needed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image1").load(function() {
        if($(this).width() < $(window).width()){
            $(this).addClass("width50");
        }else{
            $(this).addClass("width100");
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do this with just CSS.